# Diskpart Clean, thus unable to boot

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-vista, partition-recovery, diskpart

I booted my Dell Inspiron 1525 on a Vista Recovery DVD (not installation disk), ran the Command Prompt, and did like following:

```
diskpart 
list disk 
select disk 0   # which was the only hard drive I had in it
list partition 
select partition 3   # where my Operating System lied
clean
```

Now I can't even start up up my computer ("no boot sector in internal hard drive"). 
When I boot on my Recovery DVD, under System Recovery Options where I'm supposed to pick my Operating System, nothing is there anymore.

How can I get my working OS back?

All this is because I was fiddling with it trying to restore to Dell Factory Image with Repair Your Computer option missing in <kbd>F8</kbd> Advanced Boot Options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Clean` parameter of `diskpart` command removes any and all partition or volume formatting from the disk with focus.

You need to find a partition recovery software to recover your partitions.

First of all I strongly recommend to backup your whole disk using [Redo Backup](http://redobackup.org/) or any other reliable backup software you choose.

Then I recommend you use [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover your partition table. It is open source software and easy to use.

There are many bootable Live CD compilations which contain Testdisk. [Here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd) is a list of them. You may use [Ubuntu Rescue Remix](http://ubuntu-rescue-remix.org/Version12-04) or [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/) or [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php), for example. I have used them all with satisfaction.

Just download ISO file of any of such compilations and burn it to a CD to make it bootable.

Please refer to [this official page](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) if you need step by step guide for partition recovery process.

Good luck!

Comment: I couldn't find instructions on creating a bootable DVD of Testdisk.

Comment: I have added information about bootable live cd compilations.